# How do I use putExtra in FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with (9) buttons that represent different content categories. When a button is clicked, putExtra is used to supply the clicked button ID in the next activity and load the appropriate data. I am now attempting to add a ViewPager to the following sub-category activity. The problem that I am having is that I am *somewhat* unfamiliar with ViewPager and Fragments and need some advice on how to proceed. Right now I have a single method for all buttons in the main category (BrowseStyle) activity that link to ViewPagerFragmentActivity with the appropriate button id. I have 3 Fragment classes. All need some subtle work. How do I make the button click inflate my sub-category activity with the appropriate button id info and how do I retrieve it in that class? Try to be easy on me, friends.

```
public class BrowseStyle extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_style);
    }

    public void bSubCategoryClicked(View view)
    {
        Intent startActivity = new Intent(this, ViewPagerFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity.putExtra("buttonID", view.getId());
        startActivity(startActivity);
    }



    public class ViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /** maintains the pager adapter*/
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

        // retrieve "put extra" data from BrowseStyle class intent call
        // extra data is the button id that was clicked
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        // 0 is the default id
        int id = mIntent.getIntExtra("buttonID", 0);

        // initialize the pager
        this.initializePaging();

        if (savedInstanceState == ) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("buttonID", id);
            // set Fragment class Arguments
            FragmentStyleSubCatMain loadMainFrag = new FragmentStyleSubCatMain();
            loadMainFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the fragments to be paged
     */
    private void initializePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentStyleSubCatLeft.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentStyleSubCatMain.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentStyleSubCatRight.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        //
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.vp_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }

    // create inner CustomAdapter class for pageViewer swipe design
    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(supportFragManager);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case -1:
                    return new FragmentStyleSubCatLeft();
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentStyleSubCatMain();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentStyleSubCatRight();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }
}



public class FragmentStyleSubCatMain extends Fragment {

    // handle variables for each dynamic xml object utilized in this [sub-category] activity
    private TextView header, featured;
    private RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6, rb7, rb8, rb9, rb10, rb11, rb12;
    private CheckBox cbAdditives;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_style_sub_cat_left, container, false);

        // initialize the dynamic xml objects from this [sub-category] activity
        header = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        rb5 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
        rb6 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
        rb7 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
        rb8 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
        rb9 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
        rb10 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
        rb11 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
        rb12 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton12);
        featured = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_featured);
        cbAdditives = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.cb_additives);

        // retrieve "put extra" data from BrowseStyle class intent call
        // extra data is the button id that was clicked
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        // 0 is the default id
        int id = mIntent.getIntExtra("buttonID", 0);

        /* this switch statement will set the appropriate header text that needs to be displayed and
           call the appropriate method that will set the text and visibility of the radio buttons
         */
        switch (id)
        {
            case 0:
                // error handling if button id is invalid
                header.setText("Something went wrong");
                break;
            case R.id.b_lager_and_light_ales:
                header.setText(R.string.lagers);
                setLagerAndLightAlesRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_wheat_ales:
                header.setText(R.string.wheats);
                setWheatAlesRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_pale_ales_and_ipas:
                header.setText(R.string.pales);
                setPaleAlesAndIPAsRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_belgian_ales:
                header.setText(R.string.belgians);
                setBelgianAlesRB();
                break;
            case R.id.ambers_and_browns:
                header.setText(R.string.ambers);
                setAmbersAndBrownsRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_porters_and_stouts:
                header.setText(R.string.porters);
                setPortersAndStoutsRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_strong_ales_and_barleywines:
                header.setText(R.string.strongs);
                setStrongAlesAndBarleywinesRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_sours:
                header.setText(R.string.sours);
                setSoursRB();
                break;
            case R.id.b_ciders_and_meads:
                header.setText(R.string.ciders);
                setCidersAndMeadsRB();
                break;
        }
        return view;
    }



public class FragmentStyleSubCatLeft extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_style_sub_cat_left, container, false);
    }



public class FragmentStyleSubCatRight extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_style_sub_cat_right, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a similar button in each Fragment, and need to know which Fragment is showing when a button is pressed so you can customise the response?

Comment: nope. BrowseStyle extends the main activity. In the BrowseStyle activity there are 9 buttons that share the same method. I pass the button id with the intent to inflate the appropriate sub-category activity. I am now trying to make it so that I can use ViewPager (essentially flip pages) in the sub-category activity that is inflated. I have now linked the buttons to my ViewPagerFragmentActivity that I believe will control the swipe actions. I would like to carry that data forward to the sub-category activity and load the appropriate data.

Comment: i know it is confusing. I am a student and this is my first android app. sorry that i cannot be more specific.

Comment: this is kinda the direction that i am heading in the ViewPagerFragmentActivity class...

Comment: // retrieve "put extra" data from BrowseStyle class intent call
        // extra data is the button id that was clicked
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        // 0 is the default id
        int id = mIntent.getIntExtra("buttonID", 0);

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("buttonID", id);
        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        FragmentStyleSubCatMain load = new FragmentStyleSubCatMain();
        load.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: And in the FragmentStyleSubCatMain class...

Comment: int id = getArguments().getInt("buttonID", 0);

Comment: Edit your original question to add more code rather than adding comments - people have to be able to easily understand what you're asking.

Comment: my apologies Clyde, will do in future.

Comment: @JoshuaDavidEllen see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get ButtonId from BrowseStyle ,

```
  public class ViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /** maintains the pager adapter*/
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        String buttonId = getIntent().getStringExtra("buttonID");//call this line get button id from BrowseStyle Activity
        // initialize the pager
        FragmentStyleSubCatMain.mButtonId = (int) buttonId;// set your button Id like this
        this.initializePaging();
    }


}
```

In Fragment Class,

```
public class FragmentStyleSubCatMain extends Fragment {

// handle variables for each dynamic xml object utilized in this [sub-category] activity
private TextView header, featured;
private RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6, rb7, rb8, rb9, rb10, rb11, rb12;
private CheckBox cbAdditives;
publie static int mButtonId;// use this line

 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_style_sub_cat_left, container, false);

    // initialize the dynamic xml objects from this [sub-category] activity
    header = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    rb5 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
    rb6 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
    rb7 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
    rb8 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
    rb9 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
    rb10 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
    rb11 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
    rb12 = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioButton12);
    featured = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_featured);
    cbAdditives = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.cb_additives);

    // retrieve "put extra" data from BrowseStyle class intent call
    // extra data is the button id that was clicked
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    // 0 is the default id


    /* this switch statement will set the appropriate header text that needs to be displayed and
       call the appropriate method that will set the text and visibility of the radio buttons
     */
    switch (mButtonId)//use button Id like this
    {
        case 0:
            // error handling if button id is invalid
            header.setText("Something went wrong");
            break;
        case R.id.b_lager_and_light_ales:
            header.setText(R.string.lagers);
            setLagerAndLightAlesRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_wheat_ales:
            header.setText(R.string.wheats);
            setWheatAlesRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_pale_ales_and_ipas:
            header.setText(R.string.pales);
            setPaleAlesAndIPAsRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_belgian_ales:
            header.setText(R.string.belgians);
            setBelgianAlesRB();
            break;
        case R.id.ambers_and_browns:
            header.setText(R.string.ambers);
            setAmbersAndBrownsRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_porters_and_stouts:
            header.setText(R.string.porters);
            setPortersAndStoutsRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_strong_ales_and_barleywines:
            header.setText(R.string.strongs);
            setStrongAlesAndBarleywinesRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_sours:
            header.setText(R.string.sours);
            setSoursRB();
            break;
        case R.id.b_ciders_and_meads:
            header.setText(R.string.ciders);
            setCidersAndMeadsRB();
            break;
    }
    return view;

}
```

Comment: thank you Magesh! And how would I inflate my main "tab" (FragmentStyleSubCatMain) while sending that data along on the first call?

Comment: so you ask if that buttonId 1 show Fragment1 ,if buttonId2 show Fragment 2 like that ?

Comment: i would like to pass that buttonID to the first fragment page that is inflated. the id will then use switch statement to generate strings for radio buttons in that first fragment page.

Comment: the buttonID reflects various categories in the BrowseStyle class. Each category has various sub-categories associated with it. I would like to load the appropriate strings into the radio button texts that reflect the main category that was chosen in BrowseStyle.

Comment: simply create static variable to Fragment class then set value from ViewPagerFragmentActivity

Comment: take a look at where my head is i guess. i just updated the ViewPagerFragmentActivity class in my original question.

Comment: i think i need to do a little more research on ViewPager, but adjusting code with your answer here had given me a strong push in the right direction. thank you!

Comment: now i update my answer see above , if my answer helpfully up-vote my answer because then only its help other , happy to help

Comment: much more helpful! thanks again! Unfortunately, I am new to stackoverflow and only have 8 rep. I cannot up-vote until i reach 15 rep. when i do though, i will make sure to come back and up-vote.

Comment: @JoshuaDavidEllen no problem, Happy to Help